# How do I decode the contents of Apple System Logs in /var/log/DiagnosticMessages (using the command line)

Tags: command-line, logs, macos

I would like to decode the contents of the files in `/var/log/DiagnosticMessages`.

My laptop currently has 52MB of such files:

```
$ ls -l
total 53572
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   483660 Mar 11 22:48 2019.03.11.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   283433 Mar 12 22:19 2019.03.12.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   385278 Mar 13 23:58 2019.03.13.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   957492 Mar 14 18:43 2019.03.14.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   690894 Mar 15 23:39 2019.03.15.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   731637 Mar 16 16:52 2019.03.16.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   146741 Mar 17 23:59 2019.03.17.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1683982 Mar 18 18:04 2019.03.18.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  2247577 Mar 19 20:00 2019.03.19.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1608485 Mar 20 23:03 2019.03.20.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   429023 Mar 21 23:50 2019.03.21.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   599787 Mar 22 23:50 2019.03.22.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1368664 Mar 23 23:59 2019.03.23.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  2098076 Mar 24 20:46 2019.03.24.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   595091 Mar 25 23:59 2019.03.25.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   201277 Mar 26 22:00 2019.03.26.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1409147 Mar 27 23:02 2019.03.27.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1091149 Mar 28 22:55 2019.03.28.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   264362 Mar 29 21:57 2019.03.29.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1004813 Mar 30 22:21 2019.03.30.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  2597856 Mar 31 23:50 2019.03.31.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  2662448 Apr  2 00:58 2019.04.01.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  8533505 Apr  3 00:59 2019.04.02.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  6067003 Apr  4 00:39 2019.04.03.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  2345193 Apr  5 00:58 2019.04.04.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1898596 Apr  6 00:59 2019.04.05.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  2067999 Apr  7 00:45 2019.04.06.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin  1337325 Apr  7 23:27 2019.04.07.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   582943 Apr  8 23:58 2019.04.08.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin   484791 Apr  9 18:01 2019.04.09.asl
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  admin        8 Apr  9 18:01 StoreData
```

It is unclear how to read them. File shows up as type `data`.

```
$ file 2019.03.11.asl
2019.03.11.asl: data
```

And looking thru its contents you can make out some text but nothing that's very telling:

```
$ xxd 2019.03.11.asl | head -20
00000000: 4153 4c20 4442 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002  ASL DB..........
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0304 0000 0000 5c85 df11  ............\...
00000020: 0000 0080 0000 0000 0000 0760 6200 0000  ...........`b...
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0001 0000 000e 6d65 7373 6167 6574 7261  ......messagetra
00000060: 6365 7200 0001 0000 0019 636f 6d2e 6170  cer.......com.ap
00000070: 706c 652e 6d65 7373 6167 652e 646f 6d61  ple.message.doma
00000080: 696e 0000 0100 0000 1f63 6f6d 2e61 7070  in.......com.app
00000090: 6c65 2e70 6f77 6572 642e 7072 6f78 696d  le.powerd.proxim
000000a0: 6974 7957 616b 6500 0001 0000 001d 636f  ityWake.......co
000000b0: 6d2e 6170 706c 652e 6d65 7373 6167 652e  m.apple.message.
000000c0: 5f5f 736f 7572 6365 5f5f 0000 0100 0000  __source__......
000000d0: 2b63 6f6d 2e61 7070 6c65 2e6d 6573 7361  +com.apple.messa
000000e0: 6765 2e64 6172 6b77 616b 6532 6869 6461  ge.darkwake2hida
000000f0: 6374 6976 6974 796f 6e61 6300 0001 0000  ctivityonac.....
00000100: 002d 636f 6d2e 6170 706c 652e 6d65 7373  .-com.apple.mess
00000110: 6167 652e 6461 726b 7761 6b65 3268 6964  age.darkwake2hid
00000120: 6163 7469 7669 7479 6f6e 6261 7474 0000  activityonbatt..
00000130: 0100 0000 096e 6577 6461 6e63 6500 0001  .....newdance...
$
```

*EDIT*: I do not want to use the Console application. I want to understand either the file format or have a command-line program for extracting the raw data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Reading from a GUI

For anything that's system related you can typically use the Console application to view their contents. Here I've launched the application and navigated to the `/var/log/DiagnosticMessages` directory and then selected one of the ASL files, `2019.03.11.asl`:

[image: ss1]

If you're in a terminal you can launch Console directly like so:

```
$ open -a console
```

#### Reading files from the CLI

If you'd rather read these files from the terminal, you can use either the [Python library, `asl`](https://asl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) and write your application to process them or you can use the `syslog` CLI tool to read them.

For example:

```
$ syslog -f /var/log/DiagnosticMessages/2019.03.11.asl | head -20
NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.
Mar 11 00:01:10 unagi Finder[564] <Notice>:
Mar 11 00:01:40 unagi Google Chrome[7050] <Debug>:
--- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 11 00:06:42 unagi corebrightnessd[109] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 11 00:06:45 unagi ControlStrip[506] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 4 times ---
Mar 11 00:16:14 unagi Google Chrome[7050] <Debug>:
Mar 11 00:16:18 unagi ControlStrip[506] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar 11 00:17:27 unagi corebrightnessd[109] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 11 00:17:34 unagi ControlStrip[506] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 5 times ---
Mar 11 00:24:06 unagi esets_daemon[280] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 6 times ---
Mar 11 00:24:18 unagi ControlStrip[506] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 11 00:26:35 unagi corebrightnessd[109] <Notice>:
--- last message repeated 2 times ---
```

#### References

- [How to View the System Log on a Mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/356942/how-to-view-the-system-log-on-a-mac/)
- [Retrieving Console logs on Mac](https://support.omnigroup.com/console-osx/)
- [Reading ASL log file - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661070/reading-asl-log-file-python)

Comment: I don't want to use the Console application; I want to do this from the command line. That is, I want to "decode" the files, not use a program that I can't script.

Comment: @vy32 - see updates, I show how.

Comment: Very cool. `syslog -f` works!